# Resolving postgis.control location error on CentOS 7

Tags: postgis, postgresql, centos

Yum installed PostgreSQL 10 and PostGIS 2.0 on a CentOS 7 host. Got this error while creating the postgis extension on a DB:

> could not open extension control file
> "/usr/pgsql-10/share/extension/postgis.control": No such file or
> directory

The postgis.control file on the Centos 7 is actually on `/usr/share/pgsql/extension/postgis.control`

How should I resolve this? Will creating a soft link be enough?

Comment: 2.0 is fairly old now, and is [not compatible](https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiPostgreSQLPostGIS) with postgres 10.. you might want to try with 2.4

Comment: thanks for the reply. Yes I installed it from the wrong repo. I have epel and pgdg10 repo both enabled and it ended up install from epel repo.

Answer (score 0):

I have both epel and pgdg10 repo enabled. Disabling the eprl repo before installing postgis will install the proper postgis rpms for postgresql-10.